# How can I add page template after post of a post type?

Tags: php

for example in blow case :

```
www.arzdigital.com/coins/bitcoin/events/
```

or

```
www.arzdigital.com/coins/bitcoin/technical/
```

coins is a post type and bitcoin is a post for coins post type.
what is sth like events and technical in wordpress structure ? and How can I add sth like this for my post type?

Answer (score -1):

So you want to use sub categories?! Just add a new category "Bitcoin" with the parent category "Coins" and change your Settings > Permalinks to "Custom Structure" /%category%/%postname%/